# How to use Self Created Certificate in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, xamarin.uwp, makecert, self-signed-certificate

So as in the Titel said, my Problem is that i cant use my self Signed Cert to sign the app via Visual Studio.
I created 2 Certificates, one via MakeCert.exe and one in Powershell via SelfSignedCertificates as Described in here [MSDocs(Example 7)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/module/pkiclient/New-SelfSignedCertificate?view=win10-ps).

I than exported the SelfSignedCert to my Desktop Via Powershell:
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $certPath -FilePath C:\Users\*****\Desktop\****.pfx -Password $pw

But When I try to "Import" the Certificate in Visual Studio in Packages.appxmanifest in Packinging and then choose the Certificate I get this Error:

[image]

This also happens to the Certificate made with MakeCert. Both Are still Valid. Also the Link given didnt help me :/ 
I Know that i can create a Certificate in Visual Studio but i need A certificate that doesnt expire in 1 Year.

Also the Application will be a sideloaded one and therefore i cant use the Windows Store.
I also tried to Create a Appx file with MakeApp.exe to sign it manually but Make App had some problems with my AppManifest.xml file.

Comment: The default certificate that Visual Studio generates expires one year after the date on which the certificate was created, there is no ways for Visual studio to generate a certificate that is valid for more than one year.You could renew a certificate When the certificate is about to expire.

Comment: Yeah thats why I Created a self Signed Certificate wich is 2.5 Year Valid. But I can't "Add" it to Visual Studio to sign the app with.

Comment: Could you [sign your app package using the SingTool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/sign-app-package-using-signtool) instead of VS ?SignTool is a command line tool used to digitally sign an app package or bundle with a certificate.

Comment: So yeah, I created the Package via MakeApp and signed it via SignTool. Also I tested if I could just Sign the package created via VisualStudio and that worked too.